# How do I search for cards without a casting cost (excluding {0})?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

[Ancestral Vision](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAncestral%20Vision%5d) is an example of a card with a total absence of any casting cost: you can't cast it the ordinary way. In this case, you have to cast it using its Suspend ability.

[image]

I've just found that I have *no idea* how to search for these cards in Gatherer or in MagicCards.info. I can search for cards with a mana cost or converted mana cost of 0, but that also gets me cards like [Accorder's Shield](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bAccorder%27s%5d%2b%5bShield%5d).

How can I search up cards *with no mana cost* in either Gatherer or MagicCards.info?

Lands are also in this category — it's fine if this search turns lands up as well; I can exclude those by their type easily enough.

Comment: Looking at MagicCards.info it looks like for their their system doesn't differentiate between a mana cost of 0 and a mana cost of NULL, so the only way I could find involved various hacks like excluding Kobolds that aren't necessarily future proof...

Comment: @diego It's ok if the only viable method is via Gatherer. Thanks for taking a look into it.

Answer (score 8):

You can search for cards that have a CMC of 0 but don't have a mana cost of 0 or that contains X. [Here](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&cmc=+=[0]&mana=+!=[0]+!=[X]+!=[XX]+!=[XXX]&type=+![land]) is an example on Gatherer. Many of them are transform cards or tokens.

Comment: You can also skip both Innistrad blocks and Magic Origins to ditch the transform cards, leaving just the tokens and the real no-cost cards.

Comment: Instead of excluding each different occurance of `X`, you could include `mana=+!=[0]+!~[X]` and get the same result. This is safe to use even in case a card with even more Xs as costs is printed.

Answer (score 2):

You can actually directly search for all cards without a mana cost (or, more specifically, an empty mana cost) like this [[direct link](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&mana=+=[])]:

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&mana=+=[]
```

This can be input directly in the Advanced Search by submitting `Mana Cost` `and` `=`, without adding any value to the field.

[This query also excludes lands and some tokens](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&mana=+=[]&type=+!["Land"]+!["Token"]).

---

As far as I can see, there's no simple way to exclude the back faces of cards without excluding entire editions they appear in, or excluding their names one by one. The only data-wise unique qualifier is that the collector number contains `b`, however Gatherer doesn't seem to offer a search query for the collector number.

Comment: The results of the second search you linked to include tokens.

Comment: @KSFT: Wow, you're correct... I fixed the link declaration, as I can't seem to come up with a query that reliably excludes tokens in general.